# CSS Remove after if element has two classes

Tags: css

Say I have the following CSS `:after`

```
<div class="bob"></div>

.bob:after{
    background:#ff0000;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}
```

Is it possible to remove that after just using a second class?

```
<div class="bob geff"></div>

.bob:after{
    background:#ff0000;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}

.bob.geff:after{
    background:none;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `:after` won't have any effect unless you assign it a `content`. Default value for content is `none`, so

```
.bob:after{
    content:'';
    background:#ff0000;
    display: inline-block; 
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}

.bob.geff:after{
    content: none;
}
```

should work. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3hxbjqo/)

Comment: Nice one, this is much more comprehensive than my answer.